# Succesive mutex locks blocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I'm tried something by curiosity, and it seems to do not work. In the same function I do

```
std::mutex mtx1,mtx2;
mtx1.lock ();
mtx2.lock ();
mtx1.unlock ();
mtx2.unlock ();
```

Then I launch it for several thread. It unexpectedly (for me) finish in a deadlock.
I would like to understand why.

(to who is interested why I wonder such a thing, the idea was to create a mutex dictionary, and to protect the access to this dictionary of mutexes)
thanks

Comment: This looks a lot like the 5 dining philosophers problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem

Comment: Don't ever lock a mutex manually! use `std::lock_guard` or `std::unique_lock`. We're not in the 90s anymore. Worst case scenario, write your own RAII class for locking and unlocking.

Comment: These also (if used naturally) guarantee unlocking in the reverse order of locking, which is the usual discipline for avoiding nested-mutex deadlocks.

Comment: @IlBeldus No, it's not the same. Not only are the mutexes locked in a consistent order, but if the pseudocode is to be believed, each thread has their own mutexes.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9bfc4694498182e). Please post the actual code you are having a problem with.

Comment: I guess he might have shared mutexes, but even with such it works (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1963f4a432e40902). If the mutexes are locked in the consistent order, a deadlock should not happen here. The unlocking order is not important IMHO.

Comment: @Ice Are you sure that you always lock the mutexes in the same order, or is perhaps the locking order random? (that would explain the deadlock)

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/043fd468e57ace3a

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody.
@cdhowie So indeed it didn't reproduce it. I created a closer code to what I want to do:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/043fd468e57ace3a
The funny thing is that coliru does not reproduce it, meanwhile my debian stretch does! 
So I tried on a SL 6.9 it reproduces it, SL 5 does not! it seems that it's a newer kernel problem :s

Answer (score 0):

Code you posted in comment section is different from the one in your question. Your sequence looks like this:

```
mtx1.lock();    // 1
mtx2.lock();    // 2
mtx1.unlock();  // 3
                // 4
mtx1.lock();    // 5
mtx2.unlock();  // 6
mtx1.lock();    // 7
```

One thread acquires `mtx2` and tries to lock `mtx1` (line 5). Another thread locks `mtx1` and then proceeds with locking `mtx2` (line 2).

You are using different locking order for two mutexes. This is a classic example of a deadlock.

Locks should always be acquired in the same order to avoid deadlocks. Unlocking can be done in any order.